# How can I set my reactive form date input value?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

So I am trying to display this date for an input. But it's not displaying when setting the value of it in my form builder group. I would also like to be able to format it too.

this.post.startDate is of type Date

Whats in .ts

```
this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      startDate: [this.post.startDate, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      endDate: [this.post.endDate, Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    });
```

My reactive form has this

```
<form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="saveDate()">

        <label>Start Date: </label>
        <input type="date" formControlName="startDate" name="startDate" />

        <br />
        <label>End Date: </label>
        <input type="date" formControlName="endDate" name="endDate" />

        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Create Date">

      </form>
```

Comment: what does the whole form tag look like? can you post that together with the endDate input field.

Comment: @IanP. Adding that now

Comment: form tag looks good, where do you get the value for this.post? did you try setting the default value fields manually like `startDate: ['04/12/2019',Validators...]`?

Comment: @IanP. I get them from my api, the problem is I just can't seem to set the value of the date input. I tried setting it like '04/12/2019' doesn't work

Comment: @Jade see my answer

Comment: ahh cool and the api returns a date object? maybe you can try doing this `startDate:[new Date('04/12/2019'),Validators...]`..

Comment: @IanP. Yeah the api is C# asp.net core 2.2 . I tried that nothing worked new Date.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You have two possibilities to set you date as default value.

**Variant 1:**

For setting default date value to `<input>` tag with type date you should use HTML-property `value` of input-tag.

Example:

```
<form [formGroup]="editForm2">
    <input type="date" formControlName="startDate" value="{{ post.startDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}">
    <input type="date" formControlName="endDate" value="{{ post.endDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}">
</form>
```

**Variant 2 (recommended):**

You can use an built-in function `formatDate()` in angular.

*Step 1:*

Import `formatDate()` from `@angular/common` in you component typescript file.

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
```

Note: `formatDate(yourDate, format, locale)` expects 3-4 parameters.

*Step 2:*

Format your dates in definition of your form group.

```
this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      startDate: [formatDate(this.post.startDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en'), [Validators.required]],
      endDate: [formatDate(this.post.endDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en'), [Validators.required]]
});
```

Here is working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kucypd

Here is documentation of input type date: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: don't use {{  }} inside an attribute, that's bad practice!

Comment: For a form input of type `datetime-local`, the way to convert `theDate` for display appears to be this:
`formatDate(theDate,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm','en')`.  Case sensitive.

Answer (score 17):

Try the built-in *formatDate* package.

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common'
```

and then convert your date and set it to the datepicker control

```
this.yourForm.controls.controlName.setValue(formatDate(date,'yyyy-MM-dd','en'));
```

Comment: Simple as possible to be the perfect answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works. It should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, a little more functional w time zone Offset, adding binding and format transformation:

.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<input type="date" class="form-control" (change)="onMyDateChange($event)" name="myDate" formControlName="myDate" value="{{ actualDateFormGroup | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}" >
</form>
```

.ts:

```
 actualDateFormGroup = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString().split("T")[0];

 onMyDateChange(event: any) {
    this.forma.patchValue({ myDate: event.target.value });
  }
```

Then you can modify the format obtained in the myDate variable as needed in the code.

For example: 2019-10-13 to 20191013

```
 stringFormat(string){
  let date = fechaString.replace(/-/g, '');
  return date;
  }

finalDate = stringFormat(myDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem. My solution was it:

```
// another code on constructor ....
this.form = new FormGroup({
  createdDate: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  expiredDate: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  // more fields....
});
```

....

Then, in another moment I get the value of the date on coupon.createdDate...

```
    this.form.get('createdDate').setValue(new Date(coupon.createdDate).toISOString().split('T')[0]);
```

And thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the input date value for input type datetime-local works though i.e.

```
 <input id="endDate" type="datetime-local" class="form-control />
```

and in controller

```
 this.form.patchValue({
                endDate: this.schoolEvent.endDate
            });
```

So, if you need a datetime input, you can use the above.