# Angular reactive forms date setvalue

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working on Angular project, one of the components is update client component where the client's data gets populated to reactive form for editing purpose, client's info is coming from API,
i used the FormGroup.setvalue for populating the data to the form, all client's data are populated except the Date input field, would you please advice why the Date input field doesn't populate anything, please consider all these information will be resubmitted after editing,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/user.service';
import { Client } from 'src/app/models/Client';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
 selector: 'app-update',
 templateUrl: './update.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./update.component.css']
 })
 export class UpdateComponent implements OnInit {

client:Client= new Client();
editForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, private service:UserService, private router:Router,        private formBuilder:FormBuilder) { }


ngOnInit() {

 this.editForm = new FormGroup({
  id: new FormControl(),
  domain: new FormControl(),
  owner : new FormControl(),
  email: new FormControl(),
  hostComp : new FormControl(),
  cpUrl: new FormControl(),
  expDate: new FormControl(),
  cpUsername : new FormControl(),
  cpPassword : new FormControl(),
  depDate : new FormControl(),
  notices: new FormControl() 
 });



  this.route.params.subscribe(data=>{
  const id = data.id;


     this.service.getClient(id).subscribe(data=>{

     this.editForm.setValue({
      id: data.id,
      domain: data.domain,
      owner : data.owner,
      email: data.email,
      hostComp : data.hostComp,
      cpUrl: data.cpUrl,
      expDate: data.expDate,
      cpUsername : data.cpUsername,
      cpPassword : data.cpPassword,
      depDate : data.depDate,
      notices: data.notices 
    })     
    });
   });
  }

  cancel(){
 let id = this.client.id
 this.router.navigate(['/info', id]);
  }

  update(){

  this.service.updateClient(this.client).subscribe(data=>{
    this.router.navigate(['/info', this.client.id]);
  });
  }
   }
```

and the html view is like this

```
<form  [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="update()">


    <label>Domain</label>
   <input type="text"  formControlName="domain" name="domain" >

   <label>Owner</label>
    <input type="text"  name="owner" formControlName="owner" >


   <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text"  name="email" formControlName="email" >

   <label>Hosting Company</label>
   <input type="text"  name="hostcomp" formControlName="hostComp" >

     <label>CP URL</label>
   <input type="text"  name="cpurl" formControlName="cpUrl" >

    <label>Expiration</label>
    <input type="date"  name="expdate" formControlName="expDate" >

    <label>Deployment</label>
    <input type="date"  name="depdate" formControlName="depDate" >

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>

   </form>
```

Comment: please try with this when you are set date `new Date(data.expDate).toISOString().substring(0,10)`

Comment: This solve my problem, thank you kushal shah

Comment: when the client has no date, i'm having 1/1/1970 populated instead of null, do you know how to handle this issue please

Comment: simple in setValue use the ternary operator: `expDate: data.expDate?new Date(data.expDate).toISOString().substring(0,10):null`. NOTE I have no time to check, but I think that's it's only `expDate:new Date(data.expDate)`

Comment: I tried using the built-in package, see if it works for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/64135962/8490589

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be due to the different `data types`. Possibly your `date` that is coming from `api` is in `string` and you are trying to set value on input type of `date`

You can try this

```
this.editForm.setValue({
  id: data.id,
  domain: data.domain,
  owner : data.owner,
  email: data.email,
  hostComp : data.hostComp,
  cpUrl: data.cpUrl,
  expDate: new Date(data.expDate),
  cpUsername : data.cpUsername,
  cpPassword : data.cpPassword,
  depDate : new Date(data.depDate),
  notices: data.notices 
})
```

Comment: Pleasure. If this answer helped you so please accept the answer so others can also get this.