# angular 6 reactive form and input type date format

Tags: html, angular, html5-canvas

In my angular 6 application, I am developing a reactive contact form, wherein I have a date field in which the user can enter the date of birth, in the .html file I have the below code.

```
<input type="date" formControlName="dob"/>
```

and in .ts file I have code as:

```
this.contactForm= this.fb.group({
 dob:[''],
})
```

Now the issue is that when the user is selecting a date the format of the data is given as per his/her system, however, I want to set it up as MM/DD/YYYY format and so I added a placeholder in the date input as below
`<input type="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">` but this does not work as well.

Can anyone please help me how to set up the date format system independently?

Answer (score 0):

**VALIDATING**

So when you are creating the FormGroup, you can pass in validation methods and or constraints there are several of them see this.

I am assuming you want to validate the user input when the form is submitted.

```
 postalCode: [
    address?.postalCode,
    [
      Validators.pattern("YOUR REGEX"),
      Validators.required
    ]
  ],
```

In this example i am creating the child group postalCode, which consists of the default value from property postalCode on the address object (if it isn't null).

Then as the second parameter, i am passing in a array of validation options, the first one is a REGEX pattern validation constraint which takes a string value as pattern. From there on you can implement a regex pattern which works for your desired date formats.

there are also other predefined validation methods see this.
https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators

also this if you want to render validation erros messages etc. https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

i hope that helps don't be afraid to ask if you encounter issues.

**CONVERTING**

You can also convert dates submitted from the form using the built in formatDate function

import format date

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
```

formatDate(DateToBeFormated, Format, LOCALE (EN / DE) or something)

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  date: [formatDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en' [Validators.required]],});
```

for example

for additional help see this post [How can I set my reactive form date input value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55660262/how-can-i-set-my-reactive-form-date-input-value)

Comment: I am not sure if validation can control how placeholder and date input being rendered,

Comment: i am not really understanding your question, if its related to converting dates into a specific format  mm/dd/yyyy or something i can recommend angulars DatePipe https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: For other Date like operations there is also the moment.js library

Comment: i have added a short explanation of the formatDate part, if thats not what you want i dont really now what your about :D

Comment: i dont want to format after submtting the form, whenever user enters the date it should be MM/DD/YYYY and the placeholder should say MM/DD/YYYY it should not be as my system date format, current problem is that even if I keep placeholder of MM/DD/YYYY it shows me 16-Feb-2022.

Comment: so if he inputs it and the reactive form component formats it thats not what you want to achive ?

Comment: yes that is there, but at first place the placeholder is taking format of my system and thats what I dont want, if this is fixed i will format it and do it.

Comment: have you tried using the datePipe on ngModel ? <input type="date" [(ngModel)]="Students.dob|date:'dd/MM/yyyy'" name="Students.dob"> something like this ? not my solutions anymore  i am just searching

Comment: will this work on reactive form ?

Comment: also you can try predefined components like this one from kendo https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/dateinput/formats/

Comment: You could try to use it in ReactiveForms,  your usecase is interesting and in native html the placeholder format should work right ?

Comment: kendo is not a good choice as of now

Comment: const formgroup = this.formgroup .value;
     formgroup .yourDate= this.datePipe.transform(formgroup .yourDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')

in words just modify the value of the date property directly on the formGroup before rendering the form, that's all i have for you D:

Comment: i have some hope in that, keep me up to date

Comment: I appreciate your help, but that did not change the placeholder part. are you on gmail ?

Comment: gmail ? you mean the mail provider, no sadly not